# How can i resubmit CS5 ipa on AppStore?

Tags: iphone, flash, flash-cs5

Now that Apple has unbanned the use of 3rd party dev tools, how can I resubmit my ipa file on the AppStore?

Answer (score 0):

hard to say, but did you use something like http://developer.openplug.com/ IDE?

Comment: When prereleased, you could submit the ipa file to AppStore directly. I now tried with Application loader and I get the error "unable to unzip the application".